# Best approach to parse an XML and get required values

Tags: xml-parsing

Which would be the best and efficient way to parse an xml

XSLT transform ?

or

Linq to XML?

or any other way?

I am planning to change the existing xslt to "linq to xml" assuming "linq to xml" will be faster is it a good choice? will it give an noticeable performance?

Answer (score 0):

use XmlSerializer and http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ 
xml2c# code generator.